# Erro CORS em requisição com axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Bom pessoal, estou com um problema ao fazer uma requisição com axios a API da Riot games. A response retorna código 200, que é o código de quando a requisição funcionou, porém, não consigo tratar o objeto retornado pelo json por conta de uma erro que está acontecendo.
OBS: sou meio iniciante em JS

Código: 
let axios = require('axios')

```
axios.get('https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/usuario?api_key=minhaApiKey')
.then(resposta => document.write(resposta.name))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

[image: Erro que está aparecendo]

Comment: Você sabe como funciona o CORS?

Comment: Outra coisa, na imagem, você está mostrando o segredo da sua chave para a API...

Comment: Você está acessando uma API com link direto, `https://...`, ou seja, não está pegando um path do seu projeto, aparentemente essa api não permite ser utilizada desta forma, neste caso, seu domínio atual precisa estar listando como permissivo dentro do servidor desta api, para seu retorno. Isso é feito no lado servidor.

Comment: Veja [se isso te ajuda](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis).